# how to perform defragmentation on mysql table

Tags: mysql, optimization, innodb

Two InnoDB tables of MySQL are getting fragmented whenever we insert data into them.

After that when I use optimize table command, it gets defragmented.

Is there any way to avoid fragmentation as I want to add thousands of rows into table?

Comment: How did you determine they get fragmented and what does getting fragmented even mean?

Comment: I'm not sure you're entirely correct in your assessment here, and I'm also not sure why fragmentation is a problem if that's even a factor. Adding *and* removing data from a table can put pressure on the MVCC subsystem but simply adding data will never cause any form of "fragmentation".

Comment: @tadman :  Thanks for your inputs. I am new to MySQL.We are having scheduled migration activity in which we are going to add several thousands of rows into tables. We are getting fragmentation, when we are adding just hundreds of rows. So wondering about whether our migration will be successful or result into some error. That's the reason we are looking for something where we can avoid fragmentation for table.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're measuring this fragmentation. Note that if you're using an SSD-backed system then fragmentation is a non-issue, seek times are utterly irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTrees naturally gravitate toward being only 69% full.  Live with it.

Also, the statistics available (`SHOW TABLE STATUS` and equivalent metrics in `information_schema`) might scare you.  `Data_free` is often in multiples of 1MB.  Live with it.  And that's just the fragmentation that it exposes!

Defragmentation of InnoDB is mostly a waste of time, since it will promptly get fragmented due to INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE.  And even SELECT!

Why `SELECT`?  To hang onto rows that might be used by other transactions to follow the semantic rules of "transaction isolation".

`OPTIMIZE TABLE` had *some* use for MyISAM tables.  I identified 2 use cases where a monthly defrag was useful (out of perhaps 5000 tables across multiple installations).  I have yet to see significant use case for doing it in InnoDB.

Comment: The one thing, really the only thing `OPTIMIZE TABLE` does for InnoDB, is rebuild the table. This has the effect of force-loading it in memory which can briefly speed things up, but has no other long-lasting effect.

Comment: @tadman - In the process of rebuilding, `OPTIMIZE` does remove most 'free' space from most BTree blocks.  So, for a while, a table scan will have fewer blocks to touch.  This is different than the caching that you mention.

Answer (score 0):

You can force defrag by running `ALTER TABLE abc_293 FORCE;` where `abc_293` is your table name. More info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-file-defragmenting.html In my case defragging cleared up disk usage significantly. Just for one table it went down from around 22GB to around 12GB. Note that selecting data_length + index_length on the table from information_schema returned the same size before and after the defrag. It was actual disk usage that was reduced:

Before defrag in MySQL

```
MariaDB [db0]> SELECT table_name AS `Table`, round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) as `Size`  FROM information_schema.TABLES  WHERE table_schema = "xyz" AND table_name LIKE "%abc_293%" ORDER BY `Size` DESC\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Table: abc_293
 Size: 12908.05
```

On disk before defrag

```
[root@exports-syndications-db0 ~]# du -a /var/lib/mysql/ | sort -n -r | head -n 50 | grep 293
22462516    /var/lib/mysql/db0/abc_293.ibd
```

Notice the reported size difference - 22GB vs 12GB

After defrag in MySQL

```
MariaDB [db0]> SELECT table_name AS `Table`, round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) as `Size`  FROM information_schema.TABLES  WHERE table_schema = "xyz" AND table_name LIKE "%abc_293%" ORDER BY `Size` DESC\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Table: abc_293
 Size: 12138.89
```

On disk after defrag

```
[root@exports-syndications-db0 ~]# du -a /var/lib/mysql/ | sort -n -r | head -n 50 | grep 293
12607544    /var/lib/mysql/db0/abc_293.ibd
```

Notice after the defrag the sizes now match around 12GB